# Can't follow a proof in Shelah's Cardinal arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I can't follow the proof of Claim 2.6 and 2.7 of III: Jonsson algebras in inaccessible cardinals of Shelah's Cardinal arithmetic.
The part I can't follow is line 12-20 on page 130:

> If $\alpha_{\ell}, k_{\ell}$ satisfy $\otimes_{\ell}$, (so $\alpha \in
>  E^0$) then $\alpha_{\ell} > \gamma$ (as $\gamma \notin
>  C_{k_{\ell}}^{\ell}[E_{k_{\ell}}]$), so $e_{\alpha_{\ell}}$
>
> is well defined and $\alpha_{\ell} = \sup e_{\alpha_{\ell}}$; so for
>   $k \ge k_{\ell}, \epsilon_{\ell} =: \min[e_{\alpha_{\ell}} \backslash
>  \gamma]$ is well
>
> defined. Now for $k \ge k_{\ell}$, (as $\alpha_{\ell} > \gamma >
>  \beta^*$ hence $\alpha_{\ell} > \beta_{\delta^*}^{\ell}[E_k]$) we have
>
> $\epsilon_{\ell} \ge \sup[E_k \cap \alpha_{\ell} \cap
>  C_{\delta^*}^n[E_k]]$ (as $\epsilon_{\ell} \ge \gamma$ and $[\gamma,
>  \alpha_{\ell}$) is disjoint to $C_{\delta^*}^n[E_k]$)
>
> and so, looking at the definition of $C_{\delta^*}^{\ell+1}[E_k]$ with
>   $\delta, n, \alpha(*), \alpha, E$ there
>
> corresponding to $\delta^*, \ell, \alpha_{\ell}, \epsilon_{\ell}, E_k$
>   here, we get $\sup(\epsilon_{\ell} \cap E_k) \in
>  C_{\delta^*}^{\ell+1}[E_k]$. Now
>
> $\langle \sup(\epsilon_{\ell} \cap E_k) : k_{\ell} \le k < \omega
>  \rangle$ is a non-increasing sequence of ordinals, hence
>
> for some $k_{{\ell}+1}, k_\ell < k_{\ell+1} < \omega$ and for some
>   $\alpha_{\ell+1}, \alpha_{\ell+1} = \sup(\epsilon_{\ell} \cap E_k)$
>   for
>
> every $k \ge k_{\ell+1}$. So it is not hard to check
>   $\otimes_{\ell+1}$ holds.

By the definition of $C_{\delta^*}^{\ell+1}[E_k]$, it seems to me that when the author claims that $\sup(\epsilon_{\ell} \cap E_{k}) \in C_{\delta^*}^{\ell+1}[E_k]$, 
he uses the fact that there exists $\beta < \delta$ such that $|\delta| > \sup \{\text{cf}(\alpha) : \beta < \alpha \in C_{\delta^*}^{\ell}[E_k] \}$. But I can't prove it. Could someone help me? Thanks.